# ActiveMQ and Custom JAAS Login Module - Authorization?

Tags: java, activemq-classic, jaas

So I am trying to authorize specific groups with ActiveMQ. I know the following:

1. Authentication works, but as soon as I add "AuthorizationPlugin" to
   my ActiveMQ.xml, I start to get an error.
2. I used the default "ModuleClass" that points to "org.apache.activemq.jaas.PropertiesLoginModule". This works with both Authentication and Authorization (which confuses me more).

I have tried copying the contents of PropertiesLoginModule, re-creating the jar and trying to have it work, but that too still gives the same error.

The error that I am getting is:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: User user is not authorized to create: topic://ActiveMQ.Advisory.Connection
    at org.apache.activemq.security.AuthorizationBroker.addDestination(AuthorizationBroker.java:115)[activemq-broker-5.15.9.jar:5.15.9]
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerFilter.addDestination(BrokerFilter.java:174)[activemq-broker-5.15.9.jar:5.15.9]
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.region.RegionBroker.send(RegionBroker.java:454)[activemq-broker-5.15.9.jar:5.15.9]
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.jmx.ManagedRegionBroker.send(ManagedRegionBroker.java:293)[activemq-broker-5.15.9.jar:5.15.9]
    at org.apache.activemq.advisory.AdvisoryBroker.fireAdvisory(AdvisoryBroker.java:909)[activemq-broker-5.15.9.jar:5.15.9]
    at org.apache.activemq.advisory.AdvisoryBroker.fireAdvisory(AdvisoryBroker.java:836)[activemq-broker-5.15.9.jar:5.15.9]
    at org.apache.activemq.advisory.AdvisoryBroker.fireAdvisory(AdvisoryBroker.java:831)[activemq-broker-5.15.9.jar:5.15.9]
    at org.apache.activemq.advisory.AdvisoryBroker.addConnection(AdvisoryBroker.java:125)[activemq-broker-5.15.9.jar:5.15.9]
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerFilter.addConnection(BrokerFilter.java:99)[activemq-broker-5.15.9.jar:5.15.9]
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerFilter.addConnection(BrokerFilter.java:99)[activemq-broker-5.15.9.jar:5.15.9]
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerFilter.addConnection(BrokerFilter.java:99)[activemq-broker-5.15.9.jar:5.15.9]
    at org.apache.activemq.security.JaasAuthenticationBroker.addConnection(JaasAuthenticationBroker.java:71)[activemq-broker-5.15.9.jar:5.15.9]
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerFilter.addConnection(BrokerFilter.java:99)[activemq-broker-5.15.9.jar:5.15.9]
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerFilter.addConnection(BrokerFilter.java:99)[activemq-broker-5.15.9.jar:5.15.9]
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection.processAddConnection(TransportConnection.java:849)[activemq-broker-5.15.9.jar:5.15.9]
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.jmx.ManagedTransportConnection.processAddConnection(ManagedTransportConnection.java:77)[activemq-broker-5.15.9.jar:5.15.9]
    at org.apache.activemq.command.ConnectionInfo.visit(ConnectionInfo.java:139)[activemq-client-5.15.9.jar:5.15.9]
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection.service(TransportConnection.java:336)[activemq-broker-5.15.9.jar:5.15.9]
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection$1.onCommand(TransportConnection.java:200)[activemq-broker-5.15.9.jar:5.15.9]
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.MutexTransport.onCommand(MutexTransport.java:50)[activemq-client-5.15.9.jar:5.15.9]
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.WireFormatNegotiator.onCommand(WireFormatNegotiator.java:125)[activemq-client-5.15.9.jar:5.15.9]
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.AbstractInactivityMonitor.onCommand(AbstractInactivityMonitor.java:301)[activemq-client-5.15.9.jar:5.15.9]
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportSupport.doConsume(TransportSupport.java:83)[activemq-client-5.15.9.jar:5.15.9]
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.doRun(TcpTransport.java:233)[activemq-client-5.15.9.jar:5.15.9]
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.run(TcpTransport.java:215)[activemq-client-5.15.9.jar:5.15.9]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)[:1.8.0_211]
```

I don't think there's a problem with my configuration since it works with the default PropertiesLoginModule. But just incase, here's my configuration:

activemq.xml

```
activemq-domain {
    org.apache.activemq.jaas.PropertiesLoginModule required
        debug=false
        org.apache.activemq.jaas.properties.user="users.properties"
        org.apache.activemq.jaas.properties.group="groups.properties";
};

custom-login {
    x.x.x.x.MyCustomModule required
        debug=false
        org.apache.activemq.jaas.properties.user="users.properties"
        org.apache.activemq.jaas.properties.group="groups.properties";
};
```

users.properties

```
admin=admin
user=password
publisher=password
consumer=password
guest=password
```

groups.properties

```
admins=admin
users=user,admin
publishers=admin,publisher
consumers=admin,publisher,consumer
guests=guest
```

activemq.xml

```
        <plugins>
            <!-- For Authentication -->
            <jaasAuthenticationPlugin configuration="custom-login"/>

            <!-- For Authorization -->
            <authorizationPlugin>
                <map>
                    <authorizationMap>
                        <authorizationEntries>
                        <authorizationEntry queue=">" read="admins" write="admins,users" admin="admins"/>
                        <authorizationEntry queue="USERS.>" read="users" write="users" admin="users"/>
                        <authorizationEntry queue="GUEST.>" read="guests" write="guests,users" admin="guests,users"/>
                        <authorizationEntry topic=">" read="admins" write="admins,users" admin="admins"/>
                        <authorizationEntry topic="USERS.>" read="users" write="users" admin="users"/>
                        <authorizationEntry topic="GUEST.>" read="guests" write="guests,users" admin="guests,users"/>
                        <authorizationEntry topic="ActiveMQ.Advisory.>" read="guests,users,admins" write="guests,users,admins" admin="guests,users,admins"/>
                        </authorizationEntries>
                    </authorizationMap>
                </map>
            </authorizationPlugin>
        </plugins>
```

Can anybody shed some light on this? I think I have exhausted Google.

**Am I missing anything in the configuration (or doing anything wrong in the process)? Why does this work with the default ModuleClass but not my custom login module, despite me re-creating the jar?**

**Has anybody gotten authorization to work with their own custom JAAS login plugin?**

Thanks.

**Edit:**

JAAS Login Module:

```
package cz.net21;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.Principal;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.security.auth.Subject;
import javax.security.auth.callback.Callback;
import javax.security.auth.callback.CallbackHandler;
import javax.security.auth.callback.NameCallback;
import javax.security.auth.callback.PasswordCallback;
import javax.security.auth.callback.UnsupportedCallbackException;
import javax.security.auth.login.LoginException;
import javax.security.auth.spi.LoginModule;

import org.apache.activemq.jaas.GroupPrincipal;
import org.apache.activemq.jaas.UserPrincipal;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

/**
 * 
 * @author ttulka
 * 
 */
public class ActiveMqLoginModule implements LoginModule {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ActiveMqLoginModule.class);

    private static final String PASSWORD = "pass";  // we demand this password for all the users

    private static final String GROUP_FILE = "org.apache.activemq.jaas.properties.group";

    private CallbackHandler callbackHandler;    
    private Subject subject;
    private Set<Principal> principals = new HashSet<>();

    private String user;    // username 
    private Properties groups = new Properties();   

    // the authentication status
    private boolean succeeded = false;
    private boolean commitSucceeded = false;

    private File baseDir;
    private String groupsFile;

    @Override
    public void initialize(Subject subject, CallbackHandler handler, Map<String, ?> state, Map<String, ?> options) {

        this.subject = subject;
        this.callbackHandler = handler;

        // set up a name of the file for groups
        if (System.getProperty("java.security.auth.login.config") != null) {
            baseDir = new File(System.getProperty("java.security.auth.login.config")).getParentFile();
        } else {
            baseDir = new File(".");
        }
        if (!options.containsKey(GROUP_FILE)) {
            LOG.warn("The group properties file path must be set by a parameter {}.", GROUP_FILE);
        } else {
            groupsFile = options.get(GROUP_FILE) + "";
        }       
    }

    @Override
    public boolean login() throws LoginException {

        if (callbackHandler == null) {
            throw new LoginException("No callback handler supplied.");
        }

        // load groups properties
        try {
            File f = new File(baseDir, groupsFile);
            groups.load(new java.io.FileInputStream(f));
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            throw new LoginException("Unable to load group properties file " + groupsFile);
        }

        Callback[] callbacks = new Callback[2];
        callbacks[0] = new NameCallback("Username");
        callbacks[1] = new PasswordCallback("Password", false);

        try {
            callbackHandler.handle(callbacks);
            String username = ((NameCallback) callbacks[0]).getName();
            char[] passwordCharArray = ((PasswordCallback) callbacks[1]).getPassword();
            String password = new String(passwordCharArray);

            subject.getPublicCredentials().add(username);
            subject.getPrivateCredentials().add(password);

            user = username;

            // TODO authentication.
            succeeded = PASSWORD.equals(password);
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            LOG.error(e.getMessage());
            throw new LoginException("IOException occured.");
        }
        catch (UnsupportedCallbackException e) {
            LOG.error(e.getMessage());
            throw new LoginException("UnsupportedCallbackException encountered.");
        }

        return succeeded;
    }

    /**
     * Authentication successful
     */
    @Override
    public boolean commit() throws LoginException {
        if (succeeded == false) {
            return false;
        }

        // set up the user
        principals.add(new UserPrincipal(user));

        // set up the groups for the user       
        for (Enumeration<?> enumeration = groups.keys(); enumeration.hasMoreElements();) {
            String groupName = (String) enumeration.nextElement();
            String[] userList = ((String) groups.getProperty(groupName) + "").split(",");
            for (int i = 0; i < userList.length; i++) {
                if (user.equals(userList[i])) {
                    principals.add(new GroupPrincipal(groupName));
                    break;
                }
            }           
        }

        subject.getPrincipals().addAll(principals);            

        commitSucceeded = true;

        clear();

        return true;
    }   

    @Override
    public boolean logout() throws LoginException {

        subject.getPrincipals().removeAll(principals);
        principals.clear();

        succeeded = false;
        commitSucceeded = false;

        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Authentication failure
     */
    @Override
    public boolean abort() throws LoginException {
        clear();

        if (succeeded == false) {
            return false;
        }

        if (succeeded == true && commitSucceeded == false) {
            // login succeeded but overall authentication failed
            succeeded = false;
        } else {
            // overall authentication succeeded and commit succeeded,
            // but someone else's commit failed
            logout();
        }

        return true;
    }

    private void clear() {      
        groups.clear();
        user = null;
    }
}
```

(From here: http://blog.ttulka.com/activemq-jaas-custom-login-module)

Comment: Can you provide the code for your JAAS login module?

Comment: I edited the original post with the JAAS Login Module. I used the one from here: http://blog.ttulka.com/activemq-jaas-custom-login-module.

Comment: Is there a specific place to put the jar? I used “nvm package” to create the jar then I usually put it in $ACTIVEMQ_HOME/lib/extra.